# Kafka producer and JPA Transaction

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to make a composite transaction with JPA and Kafka with Spring-Kafka.
I need to avoid the message commit if the JPA transaction is rollbacked (eg when a ContraintViolationException is raised) but the following code does not working (if a ContraintViolationException is raised, the message is committed to topic).

My Kafka Configuration:

```
@Bean(name="jpaKafkaTx")
public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedTm(KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> kafkaTx, JpaTransactionManager jpaTx) {
                return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(jpaTx, kafkaTx);
}
        
... 

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaOperations<?, ?> template,
                    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                    ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory, ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedTx) {
        ...
        
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTx);
        return factory;
}
```

My Service

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "jpaKafkaTx", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void update(){
            updateDb();
            produce();

}
.. 
public void updateDb(){
            .....
            jpaRepository.save();
}
```

My KafkaProducer Service

```
public void produce(...){
            ...
            kafkaTemplate.send(message).addCallback(callback);
    
            if (callback.isError()) {
                log.error("KO");
    
            } else {
                log.info("OK");
            }
....
}
```

The Kafka isolation level is: read_committed.
Could you help me? Where I can found a complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(jpaTx, kafkaTx);`

With that configuration, the kafka transaction is committed first.

Reverse the TM order, or just inject the KTM into the container and use the `@Transactional` to manage just the JPA transaction.

Note that the `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` is deprecated with no replacement - see the comment in its javadocs.